# Is it possible to use Google Script to convert a non-searchable PDF located in Google Drive into a searchable PDF?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, ocr, drive

I would like to **use Google Apps Spript** to convert nonsearchable PDFs into searchable PDFs in which the text is **overlayed** on the PDF.

The PDFs are located in my Google Drive, and I do not want to upload the files to another website or download the files in order to do the conversion.

I have not found any resource that shows that the text can be overlayed similar to how Adobe Acrobat does the OCR conversion.  So, is it even possible to do the overlay using GAS?  I've only seen people converting to a text or Docs file.

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide a sample PDF file of nonsearchable PDF? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: What do you mean by overlaying? You want the searchable text to be pasted on top of the non-searchable one?

Comment: For example, if I take a screenshot of this webpage, and I save the screenshot as a PDF, it will be an image within the PDF.  Initially, the PDF is non-searchable--one cannot search for the words "Is it possible to use Google Script to convert" while the document is only a PDF with an image.  In Acrobat, I can run OCR, which then recognizes the text

Comment: With regard to overlaying, when Acrobat OCR recognizes the text in the image and then applies a layer of text (not visible but can be highlighted) over the text in the image. <br/><br/>I have found scripts to recognize the text in the image and export it to Google Docs, but this does not make the PDF into a searchable PDF--a PDF in which I can search for a word and locate it within the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google drive features an OCR recognition which allows you to convert images / non searchable PDFs into Google Docs files when uploading, and it also features a export function, which allows you to export Docs files to PDF. However, there is no direct conversion method and during the OCR recognition formatting will be lost. Thus, it is not possible to create PDF files with overlaying.

Your best bet will be calling an external OCR API via a POST or GET request with `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` in Apps Script. You can embed the method within a function that automatically iterates through your desired drive folers(s), finds all pdf files and uses their URLs to call the external OCR API.

Comment: With regard to it being possible to create the text overlay, this answer seems to confirm that it is not possible at this time.  So using Acrobat or similar programs is the way to go for now.  My goal is to make it easy to do content analysis, so searching the PDF and adding comments on the PDF is the reason for the overlaid text.  We can revisit this topic if Google develops this ability in the future.